# How to assess the significance of interactions between categorical variables

Tags: regression, interaction

Suppose I have a model with an interaction between two dummy variables

$$
\begin{equation}
wage = \beta_0 + \beta_1 male+ \beta_2 white + \beta_3 educ + \beta_4 (male* white) + \epsilon
\end{equation}
$$

and that the coefficient for $ \beta_4 $ is significant.

Am I able to say that the impact of being white is significantly conditioned by gender (i.e. that the coefficient for white is different across men and women)? In the case of a continuous moderator, I would plot the conditional effect of the independent variable for different values of the moderator and see whether this effect is statistically different from zero. Should I do something similar also in this case? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When variable interactions like this start being important, consider a Structural Equation Modeling (SEM) approach. Interaction terms will get the job done, but with less clarity/interpretability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say *both* the impact of being white is significantly conditioned by gender and *equally* the impact of gender is significantly conditioned by being white. You can plot the distribution of $wage$ in each of the four subgroups, for instance using box-and-whisker plots, violin plot, and even scatter plots. See for example Figure R9 here: https://wellcomeopenresearch.org/articles/4-63